# eclipse default code formatting style?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, default, code-formatting

Can someone tell me what's the default code format in eclipse? In Intellij IDEA, it is 4 4 8, I am not an eclipse user and want to enforce default code format for my project.

I want to know whether going with 4 4 8 is a good option if eclipse also provides the same